# please check my code its not checking my database its always returns false

Tags: java, mysql

```
package com.vloginDao;

import java.sql.DriverManager;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class LoginDa0 {
    String sql = "select * from login where uname=? and pass=?";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employe";
    String username ="root";
    String password = "123";
    public boolean check(String uname,String pass) {

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con =  DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
            PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            st.setString(1, uname);
            st.setString(2, pass);
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
            if(rs.next()){
                return true;
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;

    }
}
```

Please verify it I am a new to this so help me to if there are any faults in my code.

I am always getting false as my return its not connecting my database I think.

My database name is `employe` and table name is `login`

Comment: How are you calling that method? And does your database have a row corresponding to the parameters you're passing to the method? Does the query work if you do the query directly on the db?

Comment: i called the method in another file named(Login.java) ,and yes the query working directley on the db . and i also have a row corresponding to parameters please help me to solve this

Answer (score 1):

I guess issue can be caused by fact that you are using `PreparedStatement` and try to run `Statement.executeQuery(sql)` method which is not allowed by interface specification, for details you can look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery(java.lang.String)).
Instead you can use `PreparedStatement.executeQuery()` method.

```
PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(sql);
st.setString(1, uname);
st.setString(2, pass);
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
```